# Android Caching-Saving local more than 64kb image

Tags: android

i am creating a cloud app. The app is "cloud photo gallery".

I wanna to build low quality (200~kb) images and send them to the user (android app). There will be option for downloading the original version. But, only for viewing images you can't transfer all the time ~2MB/images... so thats why i am creating another, low quality version.

So, the problem is with android. I can't save 200k as Base64 string to DB, and then send to android, so android save the Base64 string to local android DB.

What i can do? the only way is to save them as image files localy? But... what about permissions...

I am thinking to:

- Save them locally.
- OnLoad, if there are chached (saved in android), load from android and not cloud. 
  -There will be button to update-sync. [So, no need every time to open activity to download from cloud]

  - If something goes wrong (permission excpetion) i will download from cloud.

I just wanted to save them to local db...

Comment: 'I can't save 200k as Base64 string to DB'. To which DB where? And why would you?

Comment: Because somehow i must save it offline. You can convert image to Base64, save the string in DB (or a file?) and then, when you open the app, you retrive it from database and don't ask the server.

Comment: You just cache the files as file on the Android device. What's the problem with that? Nowhere you need base64.

Comment: Actually there is no problem. But i am thinking for permissions. If the user accept permission before install the app, can android block acces to storage disk of device later?

Comment: Which permission(s)?

Comment: Accessing storage. Saving to device.

Comment: That is what you want to do yes. But i asked you about which permissions you were talking. So you are supposed to name them exactly of course.

Comment: I don't know exactly to tell you. I am new with Android and i don't know all permissions. How exactly are called.